# GWT Tab Layout Panel horizontal slide in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

we've run in a bit of a problem. Our web app developed in GWT has a layout with the "Tab Layout Panel" feature. Now, the horizontal slide animation works great in every browser except Chrome (version > 22).

When the user clicks on one of the tabs that should trigger the slide animation, it simply starts to scroll left to right in some kind of loop, without stopping itself until GWT Chrome plugin crashes (and that doesn't happen always).

We tried on multiple computers, different OS's, browsers and platforms, but the results is always the same. 
Chrome seems not to like the GWT Tab Layout Panel animation.

this is an example web app created for this question..it still has this akward loop-ish left-right slide.

```
public class MyWebApp implements EntryPoint {
  // A simple data type that represents a contact.
  private static class Contact {
    private final String address;
    private final String name;

    public Contact(String name, String address) {
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
    }
  }

  // The list of data to display.
  private static List<Contact> CONTACTS = Arrays.asList(new Contact("John",
      "123 Fourth Road"), new Contact("Mary", "222 Lancer Lane"), new Contact(
      "Zander", "94 Road Street"));

  public void onModuleLoad() {

    // Create a CellTable.
    CellTable<Contact> table = new CellTable<Contact>();

    // Create name column.
    TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
      @Override
      public String getValue(Contact contact) {
        return contact.name;
      }
    };

    // Make the name column sortable.
    nameColumn.setSortable(true);

    // Create address column.
    TextColumn<Contact> addressColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
      @Override
      public String getValue(Contact contact) {
        return contact.address;
      }
    };

    // Add the columns.
    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
    table.addColumn(addressColumn, "Address");

    // Create a data provider.
    ListDataProvider<Contact> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Contact>();

    // Connect the table to the data provider.
    dataProvider.addDataDisplay(table);

    // Add the data to the data provider, which automatically pushes it to the
    // widget.
    List<Contact> list = dataProvider.getList();
    for (Contact contact : CONTACTS) {
      list.add(contact);
    }

    // Add a ColumnSortEvent.ListHandler to connect sorting to the
    // java.util.List.
    ListHandler<Contact> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<Contact>(list);
    columnSortHandler.setComparator(nameColumn, new Comparator<Contact>() {
          public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2) {
            if (o1 == o2) {
              return 0;
            }

            // Compare the name columns.
            if (o1 != null) {
              return (o2 != null) ? o1.name.compareTo(o2.name) : 1;
            }
            return -1;
          }
        });
    table.addColumnSortHandler(columnSortHandler);

    // We know that the data is sorted alphabetically by default.
    table.getColumnSortList().push(nameColumn);

    // Create a tab panel
    TabLayoutPanel tabPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(2.5, Unit.EM);
    tabPanel.setAnimationDuration(1000);
    tabPanel.getElement().getStyle().setMarginBottom(10.0, Unit.PX);
    tabPanel.getElement().getStyle().setHeight(1000, Unit.PX);
    tabPanel.getElement().getStyle().setWidth(720, Unit.PX);
    tabPanel.getElement().getStyle().setLeft(14, Unit.PX);

    // Add a home tab
    String[] tabTitles = {"Prova1", "Prova2", "Prova3"};
    HTML homeText = new HTML("<h1>Prova1</h1>");
    tabPanel.add(homeText, tabTitles[0]);
    FlexTable ft = new FlexTable();
    ft.setText(0, 0, "upper-left corner");
    ft.setText(2, 2, "bottom-right corner");
    VerticalPanel p = new VerticalPanel();
    p.add(ft);
    // Add a tab
    HTML moreInfo = new HTML("<h1>Prova2</h1>");
    tabPanel.add(p, tabTitles[2]);   

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get().add(table);
    RootPanel.get().add(tabPanel);
  }
```

}